# Vulkan API dump layer equialent in Metal

Tags: debugging, metal

It's a while I'm playing with Metal API, but neither in Objective-C nor Swift. Currently I have a black screen problem with one of the examples of the Metal in my target language.

I had same problem in Vulkan API too, but there was a nice [layer (VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump)](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.0.51.0/windows/layers.html) that dump the every usage of the Vulkan API, parameters and values in the command line and I could compare it with a working project.

(My question is) Is there any tool or utility that can do the same functionality in Metal?

Comment: If you're using Xcode to develop with your mystery language, you can use the Capture GPU Frame menu to take a capture of a frame and see all API calls and their parameters. Alternatively, you can activate the validation layer by setting environment variable `METAL_DEVICE_WRAPPER_TYPE` to 1. This won't give you a full dump, but it will log or assert when invalid calls are made.

Comment: The language that I'm using is Rust and I already used `Capture GPU Frame` it shows a state of a frame not function calls, one of the problem when you try to use other languages instead of native language (Objective-C/Swift) is wrong binding, wrong parameter values and types, If you can have a utility like the layer mentioned above you can see what is wrong and where it is happening.

Comment: If you already have a Vulkan version of what you are trying to build...you might also consider using [MoltenVK](https://moltengl.com/moltenvk/), to run Vulkan on Metal devices...instead of writing a Metal backend yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I already have seen MoltenVK, but I do not like any dependency (except native provided libraries), and I know there are lots of other developers like me. And also this is a non-free library.